# android child and parent list

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to get a layout in android in the below shown format with list view??

Following the tutorial(http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/) i was able to get the normal list view.

But unable to get a layout as shown below

[image: Sample View]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It's called `ExpandableListView`. For your reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExpandableListView` is a good way if you want to collapse/expend your listview items or you can use multiple row adapter like

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View mView = convertView;
    ViewHolder mHolder = null;
    ViewHeaderHolder mHeaderHolder = null;
    YourRowItem item = getItem(position);
    boolean isSection = item.isHeaderItem();
    if (mView == null) {
        if (isSection) {
            mHeaderHolder = new ViewHeaderHolder();
            mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_row, null);
            // initialise your view
            mView.setClickable(false);
            mView.setFocusable(false);
            mView.setOnClickListener(null);
            mView.setTag(mHeaderHolder);
        } else {
            mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, parent, false);
            mHolder = new ViewHolder();
            // initialise your view 
            mView.setTag(mHolder);
        }
    } else {
        if (isSection) {
            mHeaderHolder = (ViewHeaderHolder) mView.getTag();
        } else {
            mHolder = (ViewHolder) mView.getTag();
        }
    }

    if (!isSection) {
        // add values to child view
    } else {
        // add values to header view
    }
    return mView;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return ((YourRowItem) getItem(position)).isHeaderItem() ? 0 : 1;
}
```